# htaccess 301 - Folder named a number remains in redirected URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am redirecting a bunch of URL's in htaccess

I have an issue where if the URL to be redirected has a folder named a number that folder remains in the redirected uRL

eg:
redirecting: /index.php/news/15/rhs **to** http://www.domain.com/news/rhs/  **ends up as** http://www.domain.com/news/15/rhs/

I dont want the **/15/** in the final URL

All other redirects that don't contain folders named numbers work fine.

The new site is Wordpress and current mod_rewrite is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't think this has anything to do with your htaccess rules, you're better off looking at your wordpress setup and plugins.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - Very few plugins installed, and where the URL does not have a number the redirect works fine?....any clues as to what you think might be wrong with the Wordpress set-up that could cause this?

Comment: Well, if anyone is intereted I found the problem. I tried in a different browser and all redirects worked fine (should have been the first thing I did really) I think somehow Firefox had cached a bad redirect and somehow cached the bad re-directed folder structure, even though I cleared the cache several times?....oh well, in the meantime I learned a bit about Apache redirects.